# PIL Opening JPEG Missing Photoshop

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg

I'm opening a jpg file with Pillow/PillowPIL. But am getting a missing photoshop error.

The environment is a portable python WinPython-64bit-2.7.13.1Zero base installation, plus the Pillow-PIL and some other packages installed.

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> Image.open("snap_thm_0.jpg")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\you\Desktop\penvgui\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2690, in open
    im = _open_core(fp, filename, prefix)
  File "C:\Users\you\Desktop\penvgui\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2676, in _open_core
    im = factory(fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\you\Desktop\penvgui\lib\site-packages\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py", line 783, in jpeg_factory
    im = JpegImageFile(fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\you\Desktop\penvgui\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 103, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "C:\Users\you\Desktop\penvgui\lib\site-packages\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py", line 373, in _open
    handler(self, i)
  File "C:\Users\you\Desktop\penvgui\lib\site-packages\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py", line 139, in APP
    self.info["photoshop"] = photoshop
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'photoshop' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

Any other packages will be needed to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I checked variable `photoshop` in file `JpegImagePlugin.py` for Python 2.7 (PIL 6.0.0) and Python 3.7 (PIL 5.4.1). It exists only in 2.7 so it can be new function in PIL 6.0.0. Better send this to PIL's author

Comment: would it just work if I delete the variable from the  source in that package?

Comment: you would have to delete line `self.info["photoshop"] = photoshop` or assign any (default) value to variable `photoshop` before line `self.info["photoshop"] = photoshop`.

Comment: ok, I assigned a None replacing the photoshop variable reference. it works now. thanks! would you want to make your comment an answer?

Answer (score -1):

As the comments indicated, the temporary work-around provided by furas is to assign a None in place of photoshop.

Comment: As the comments indicated, the temporary work-around was provided by @furas

Comment: I'll be glad if furas writes it in an answer.